# Regex pattern not work like expect

Tags: javascript, regex

I have pattern

```
/[^!]!(\z|[^!])/
```

And i have string: 
"My string here!"

i need check if string have 1 exclamation (but not !! or !!!)

Comment: What does `\z` represent?

Comment: You can use a regular expression like this `var regex = /!{2,}/` to check if there is more successive `!` and reverese the test using NOT like this `if(! regex.test(str))`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded what i needed. Because i need check not only end but also and middle of string

"My! string" and "My string!"

```
/([^!]![^!])|([^!]!$)/
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Your regex is the same as `[^!]!(?!!)` Do you really need to capture the before/after ?

Comment: If `!!` matches you know there is at least 2 or more adjacent in the string. You don't even need a regex for that.

Comment: @sln  String with no "!" is also bad. I can count total "!" because it's can be on two places ex.: "Some! Text is here!"

Comment: Well, in your regex, your not checking there is at least a single ! anyway. Still no reason to use a regex. Use string function to find first of ! (pass) and first of  !! (fail).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](https://regex101.com/r/u5v8Sd/1) if I understood your question correctly

```
\A([^!]*)[!]{1}\Z
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this ? It should work

```
/\w+!{1}$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp` `/!(?=!)/` to match `!` followed by `!`, `!` operator, `RegExp.prototype.test()`

```js
var str = "My string here!";
var re = /!(?=!)/;
console.log(!re.test(str));

var str = "My string here!!";
console.log(!re.test(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
/[^!]+!$/
```

your patterm:

```
/[^!]!(\z|[^!])/
```

means 
"first character is not !, second character is !,
third character, should be last character or any character which is not !"