# Select class name except some via Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have HTML elements that I want to extract custom class name from and ignore the rest of the elements in returning the result

There is no DOM available, only string manipulation.

Ex:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="start">
    <h1> Example Name</h1>
    <div>
      <h1> Example Word</h1>
      <div>
        <!-- From Here -->
        <div class="correct">
          <div>
            <h1> Example Word</h1>
            <h2> Example Word</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- To Here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get to the HTML Elements pane starting with class = 'correct "and whatever is inside.

Is there a way only via Regex? Without for loop or anything else
If there is a method: I need to get all the results with class = "correct" in case it is repeated

And also conditional cases, for example:
If it doesn't find class = "fakename" it searches for class = "correct" to find an existing class

To be the result that is returned :

```html
<div class="correct">
  <div>
    <h1> Example Word</h1>
    <h2> Example Word</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regex Only Because I do not have page control, or in this sense, a side server on the cloudflare worker, and js render is not done , I cannot execute a document or queryselector

I tried

```
<a(?!.*href=["']\/["']).*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52950777/14592575 AND https://stackoverflow.com/a/42864938/14592575

Comment: What does the `<a(?!.href=["']/["']).?>(.*?)</a>` have to do with a div?

Comment: It is just an example, but I want an example to exclude some

Comment: So this is server side JS and no DOM available?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I can only execute regex, for loop and internal stuff from string, because basically the HTML code is in a variable

Comment: _“because basically the HTML code is in a variable”_ - and how exactly is that stopping you from feeding it to a parser …?

Comment: Because the cloudflare worker does not allow this, there is no access to perform such a queryselector, the results are only returned via Json

Comment: No DOM can be executed because it is a side server that is not a page that already exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **It is not possible to do what you want with a plain regular expression.**

The reason is that regular expressions recognize regular languages, and in this case you need to take into account the amount of `<div>...</div>` inside the body of your tag, making your problem a non-regular language.

- In case the body of your tag didn't contain any other `<div>`s in it, the expression would be simple `/<div[^>]* class=\"correct\"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/`

  ```js
      text = 'something <div class="correct">your <a href="example">text</a> here</div> more stuff'
      regexp = /<div[^>]* class=\"correct\"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/
      console.log(text.match(regexp)[1])
  ```
- But in any other case I recommend you to do another kind of processing.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this pattern

```
/<div class="correct">([\s\S]*?)(?:<\/div>)/g
```